# Update UI after running on another thread

Tags: c#

I have the following code which gets some information from a google sheets which runs async:

```
private async void getCodes()
    {
        ArrayList codes = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return GoogleAPI.GetDates();
        });
        foreach (DateTime date in codes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("**************");
            Debug.WriteLine(date);
            codesList.Items.Add("Test");
        }
    }
```

The `codesList.Items.Add("Test");` line crashes the application as its then trying to run the foreach on the background thread rather than the main thread. The writelines work fine.

> 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Research shows I should be able to use:

```
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
```

To run it on the main thread, but this crashes with:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.get returned null

Which according to the documentation is correct for a desktop app. If it makes a difference I'm using project reunion

Comment: The only applicable one at the moment might be project reunion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the correct way of doing it but moves the UI code to another function, so ended up with

```
private async void GetCodes()
    {
        codes = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return GoogleAPI.GetDates();
        });
        SetupCodesBox();
    }

    private void SetupCodesBox()
    {
        foreach (DateTime date in codes)
        {
            codesList.Items.Add(date);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
await codesList.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    foreach (DateTime date in codes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("**************");
        Debug.WriteLine(date);
        codesList.Items.Add("Test");
    }
});
```

Another suggestion might be to edit your code to:

```
codes = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    return GoogleAPI.GetDates();
}).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: That gives me an error - 'CoreDispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no accessible extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'CoreDispatcher' could be found

Comment: @CeriTurner What is the type of `codeList` object?

Comment: It is a ComboBox

Comment: @CeriTurner Oh, it's UWP platform - updated answer accordingly.